# How to count how many different vowels are in one word from text file in C?

Tags: count, letters

I am confused about counting how many differents vowels are in one word? This is were i got so far... I am saving word by word in the variable word[] and then check char by char whether is vowel or not... but i don't know how to count how many **different vowels are in the word?** Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
int i,j,words = 0;
while(fgets(row,MAX,f) != NULL)
{
    int flag = 0;
    int n = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(row); i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(row[i]))
        {
            if(!flag)
            {
                flag = 1;
            }
            word[n++] = row[i];
        }
        else if(flag)
        {
            flag = 0;
            word[n] = '\0';

            for(j = 0; j < strlen(word);j++)
            {
                if(isvowel(word[i]))
                {
                    c = word[i];
                }
                // i stopped here cause i donno how to check whether the char is different from all the others
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you find each vowel, simple set a flag of an array to note the vowel was found.  Then count the number of flags.  The trick is to effectively convert `c` (the vowel) into an index - that is where you are stuck.

`char *strchr(const char *s, int c)` is useful.  It locates the first occurrence of `(char) c` in the string pointed to by `s`.  Converting the result to an index for the flag array is then easy.

Let's say `'A'` is the same as `'a'` for vowel counting.

```
int DifferentVowelCount(const char *s) {
  static const char *Vowels = "AaEeIiOoUu";
  bool VowelExist[5] = { 0 };
  while (*s) {
    char *p = strchr(Vowels, *s);
    if (p != NULL) {
      int index = (int) (p - Vowels);  // index is 0 to 9
      index /= 2;
      VowelExist[index] = 1;
    }
    s++;
  }
  int sum = 0;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (VowelExist[i]) {
      sum++;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay it seems like the function for counting the different vowels in one word is created manually, but this solution really works and here it is:

```
int diff_vowels(char *word)
{
    char a = 'a',b = 'e', c = 'i', d = 'o', e = 'u';
    int a1 = 0,b1 = 0,c1 = 0,d1 = 0,e1 = 0;
    while(*word)
    {
        if(isalpha(*word))
        {
            if(tolower(*word) == 'a') a1 = 1;
            else if(tolower(*word) == 'e') b1 = 1;
            else if(tolower(*word) == 'i') c1 = 1;
            else if(tolower(*word) == 'o') d1 = 1;
            else if(tolower(*word) == 'u') e1 = 1;
        }
        word++;
    }
    return a1 + b1 + c1 + d1 + e1;
}
```